# UDP client not receiving reply from server with multiple IP addresses

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp

I have a UDP client that calls connect(), send() and recv().

The server has multiple IP addresses. If the reply from the server is not from the same IP as the query, then recv() times out. I have read elsewhere that this might be because the client is calling connect(), so it will only accept a reply from the same IP.

Is there a way to ensure the server always replies from the same IP as the query? I would like the server to listen on all interfaces.

Update: If the client does not call connect() and calls sendto() instead of send(), then recv() correctly receives the reply from the server. I would still rather fix it on the server side by sending the reply from the same IP that the query came from. There is no routing happening on the server, it's one network interface with several IPs.

Comment: Please write a snippet to see the code. Also I don't believe recv fails, at most it will receive nothing. Finally, I don't believe the server receives a message in one IP address and send the response from a different IP address if there is NAT in the middle. You should provide more details if you want some help

Comment: I should have been clearer. recv() is timing out.

Comment: If I remember this correct, the client will be establish a communication on a port number and ip received with the udp package, when transmit into the server. The server should return to the same port number. Sometimes firewall scenarios can cause problem require something called "udp hole punching", but its not related to multiple client issue. If you have multiple clients you may have a look at thread safe coding to keep the clients apart.

Comment: Firewall disabled on client and server for testing. The datagram is making it back to the client, but recv() is ignoring it because of the different source IP address. I have since confirmed that the problem does not occur if the client does not call connect() and calls sendto() instead of send().

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense if the client calls connect to one IP address and port, it won't receive a UDP datagram sent from a different IP or port.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I understand why it's happening, but was hoping to find a solution on the server. I know you asked for a code sample. I am trying to put one together, but this is part of a larger library, so the code is not all in one place. I don't think there is anything wrong with the existing code, it's working as it should by default. I would like to change the default behaviour to use the same IP for incoming and outgoing datagrams.

Comment: @upl8, the solution in the server is simple. Now I understand your problem you don't need to show code. Basically you will have to make the server send the response over the same socket it received the message.

Comment: I have double-checked, and the socket is the same for receiving and sending. It looks like Windows only creates one socket for the NIC, even if it has multiple IPs. Is this what you would expect? If that is the case, then it cannot know from the socket alone which IP address to use.

Comment: @upl8, well, as you explain in you question, it seems you solved it with connect and sendto. Without looking at code, I think it is not necessary to change the server. Can you show client code? It is probable the problem you had in the client with recv() timeout is because before the client call recv after having sent a message, the server already sent the response and then the client doesn't read it. That could happen when you didn't call bind or connect before sending a message in UDP. Try adding a sleep(1) in the server before responding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your server to listen on all ip's and all ports you'll need to program at the ethernet layer (raw sockets). Check out this [link](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html).

When programming in raw sockets you can check in your code for the IP address that the datagrams were addressed to and respond from the appropriate IP.